# MySQL doesn't update properly

Tags: mysql, laravel

**I am trying to update status for users. code works fine .but it can't update in DB**

controller.php

```
public function update_customer(Request $request)
    {
    
       $sid = 1;
       $setting['setting'] = Settings::editGeneral($sid);
       $site_max_image_size = $setting['setting']->site_max_image_size;
       $name = $request->input('name');
       $username = $request->input('username');
         $email = $request->input('email');
         $user_type = $request->input('user_type');
         $status =$request->input('status');
         
         
        $data = array('name' => $name, 'username' => $username, 'email' => $email, 'user_type' => $user_type, 'password' => $pass, 'earnings' => $earnings, 'user_photo' => $user_image,'status'=>$status, 'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
 
            
            
            Members::updateData($token, $data);
            return redirect($page_url)->with('success', 'Update successfully.');
          }
   }
```

model.php

```
public static function updateData($token,$data){
    DB::table('users')
      ->where('user_token', $token)
      ->update($data);
  }
```

**how to solve it??**

Comment: you never defined the `$token` variable

Comment: i defined $token.Update successfully msg is coming but it didn't update in db

Comment: okay sure, what line did you define the variable `$token` in `update_customer`?

Comment: Have you tried forceUpdate instead of update ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Model class instead of `DB` Facade. Like below:

User.php

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name' , 'username' , 'email' , 'user_type' , 'password' , 'earnings' , 'user_photo' ,'status', 'updated_at'
];
    
public static function updateData($token,$data)
{
    User::where('user_token', $token)
            ->update($data);
}
```